# Multimap in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, multimap

I need a collection that stores entries as key-value pairs (so I can look up values by a key), but I need one that allows multiple values to share the same key using hibernate

Answer (score 11):

A map with multiple values for one key is known as a multimap - there's an implementation in the Apache commons library. Hibernate does not support this kind of collection directly, but it can be extended to do so relatively easily by implementing the `UserCollectionType` interface. This [blog article](https://xebia.com/blog/mapping-multimaps-with-hibernate/) describes how to do it in detail.

Comment: cool answered my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545047/hibernate-collections-of-collections

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score -1):

I have also found something relevent

> http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)

So can prefer this also.

Answer (score -1):

There is a [multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) over on [google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). I don't know if they are hibernate compatible though.